# Custom Post Type Loop breaking php

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, advanced-custom-fields

My While loop is breaking the rest of my PHP on the site. Below I put my code that is working but again breaking the rest of the site. Any Suggestions

```
$query = array( 'post_type' => 'slides', 'orderby' => 'ASC' );
$loop = new WP_Query($query);

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

        $title = get_the_title();
        $image_object = get_field('slides');
        $alt = $image_object['title'];
        $sizes = $image_object['sizes'];
        $image = $sizes['slider'];

        echo '<div>';
        echo '<div class="slide">';
        echo '<img src="' . $image . '" alt="' . $alt . '" />';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';


endwhile;
```

Comment: Do you get an error message? What exactly do you mean by 'broken' can you ellaborate?

Comment: `ASC` is not a valid `orderby` argument, it's `'order' => 'ASC'`

Comment: I do not get an error message. What I am doing is running the the function the_field() from ACF and it is not returning any data a string of anything.

Answer (score 0):

A few points:

- Instead of `while(): endwhile;` Use `while() { }`
- You didn't check to see if any posts were found, `if($loop->have_posts()){}` will do the trick
- You didn't cleanup after your query, inside the if statement mentioned above, make a call to `wp_reset_postdata();` before your closing brace
- Avoid generic variables like `$query` for your args that may already be used elsewhere. `$args` may be a more appropriate name

Comment: why would it matter which `while` syntax is used?

Comment: 1: it violates the WP Coding standards, 2: IDEs and editors hate it and won't pick up on it when doing highlighting and auto-indenting, 3: not all server setups have the shorthand turned on, 4: consistency, a lot of plugins and code examples use {} style, and the shorthand while seems almost exclusive to post loops ( copypasta post loops may I add ), and as a result a mishmash of styles is encouraged which is counterproductive

Comment: 1: it's odd that the default themes violate the coding standards and use this style for all loops, no? 2: depends on the IDE 3: it's not shorthand, it's alternate syntax, it's not something that's enabled/disabled. it really just comes down to preference, you should state it's a matter of opinion and not a reason why the code may be broken.

Comment: @Milo Agree that it's not a shorthand. About the Coding "Standards": I guess it's not worth the time discussing this. Maybe you've followed Rarsts "quest" to get a definitive answer on if it's allowed to use `file()/file_put_contents()/$wp_filesystem` in Themes. About the IDEs) As long as I've used IDEs, there wasn't a single one recognizing `end*`, `extract()` or `global` outside the same file. The ones who don't do this (out of my head) are: Eclipse/Aptana/PHPStorm. Which one do you know about that can do this?

Comment: 1: Breaking the rules is not an excuse for others break them 2: I'm not aware of such an IDE but if it exists it's in a minority 3: okay alternate syntax but there are still real pitfalls to using it, sure you can be careful and have clean pretty code with that syntax but that takes more effort

Comment: But finally, I said points, not critical grave errors. If we're being technical and picky, we can cross off doing the if statement, and the last one. We could even use query_posts. I don't appreciate you picking out something because of personal preference despite their being non-personal real practical reasons for not using alt syntax.

Comment: @kaiser I don't know of any that do what you specify, I use TextMate with a customized PHP bundle, technically not an IDE, but can properly identify and indent alternate syntax blocks.

Comment: @TomJNowell - was just a suggestion to clarify your response, don't take it so personally

Comment: I stand by my thorough defence